# Script references in MasterPage or individual pages?

Tags: javascript

I there any benefit to putting the javascript references in individual pages vs the master page in terms of number of reloads and data transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is ASP.Net. Given that, no benefit. The master page and the individual page are both processed on the server side and send across as HTML. There will be a benefit of reduced loads/reduced data transfer if you enable caching of the javascript files.